# openTBS - new page after 4 rows in table

Tags: php, libreoffice, openoffice-writer, odt, opentbs

i need to create a page break in my ods file after 4 rows in my table.

i have tried some suggestion i found here but nothing worked.

Here is my code for the table:

```
[ps.pos] [ps.title;block=table:table-row][ps.description;block=table:table-row][ps.amount;block=table:table-row] [ps.singleprice;block=table:table-row;frm='0.000,00'] € [ps.sum;block=table:table-row;frm='0.000,00'] €
```

The table has 5 cells. It is an table for invoice positions.

Does someone know how i get opentbs to create a new page and continue the table?

Answer (score 0):

Note: your template snippet can be simplified to:

```
[ps.pos] [ps.title;block=tbs:row][ps.description][ps.amount] [ps.singleprice;frm='0.000,00'] € [ps.sum;frm='0.000,00'] €
```

ODT files do not allow to force a page break in a table. So what you're trying to do is not possible.

A workaround solution is to  repeat several similar tables separated by a page-break instead of one table. This ca be done using the [Serial Display](http://www.tinybutstrong.com/manual.php#html_block_serial) feature of TinyButStrong.

Here is how your snippet could be:
Note that the table should have the property « page break before »

```
| Position [ps;block=tbs:table;serial] | Title        | Price              |
| [ps_1.pos;block=tbs:row]             | [ps_1.title] | [ps_1.singleprice] |
| [ps_2.pos;block=tbs:row]             | [ps_2.title] | [ps_2.singleprice] |
| [ps_3.pos;block=tbs:row]             | [ps_3.title] | [ps_3.singleprice] |
| [ps_4.pos;block=tbs:row]             | [ps_4.title] | [ps_4.singleprice] |
```